# GitExtensions replacing # with underscore. How to turn it off?

Tags: git-extensions

Title is quite self-describing. When I create new branch and name it e.g. bug#72958 it is renamed to bug_72958 during creation. This wasn't happening few days ago. But then I had to reinstall my OS. With new installation of GitExtension it does this rubbish. Can you please advice me how to turn it off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug should be fixed in new version (2.49.01 not yet released) https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/3507